# Non-ascii characters stops mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, non-ascii-characters

This SQL has failed.

SQL is

```
INSERT INTO
    `migration_loose_terms`
    (`source`,`field`,`term`,`lastaccess`)
VALUES
    ('services.media','keywords','spermatozoïde','2012-04-25 12:00:00')
```

Because it contains a weird `(ï)` character.

What function do you use in php/mysql to weed out the nonascii characters to be stripped or to make that word somehow into mysql?

Comment: I make sure that everything uses UTF-8: my tables, the PHP-MySQL connection, within PHP, within the browser...

Comment: like this; Incorrect string value: '\xEFde' for column 'term' at row 1

Comment: for where statements always use N in front of the value you're looking for example: select value from table where value = N'value';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to strip the non ASCII characters you can use the following code :

```
<?php
$input = "Clean the non ASCII äócharacters.";
$output = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $input);
echo $output;
?>
```

otherwise, have you tried to wrap the word in question with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) ?